# Source for hermes JMS

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, soapui, hermes-jms

It looks like `Hermes JMS` is no longer maintained. I was wondering if the source is available anywhere. It appears that only the jar files are available sourceforge. We are planning on using `SoapUI` to test some XML services exposed through `ActiveMQ`. We are concerned that we will painting ourselves into a corner if there is neither active maintenance or source. I looked for alternatives to Hermes.

It seems that `JMSToolbox` may be a long term solution, but the support for `SoapUI` and `ActiveMQ` have not matured yet. Any suggestions for other solutions would also be appreciated.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/hermesjms/ ?

Comment: HI. I'm the author of JMSToolBox. The JTB plugin for ActiveMQ should work well. If not, please expose your problems and I will fix them. I was thinking about adding SoapUI support in JTB, but it happens that the "new" plugin features of SoapUI is only exposed to the paying version, not to the FOSS version, so I decided to put that development in stand by as the "legacy" way to integrate with SoapUI seems very very cumbersome. I'm thinking about exposing some JTB features via REST (thanks to embedded jetty) Maybe if you describe your test/use case, I could see what could be done in JTB

Comment: BTW the source for HermesJMS is here: https://sourceforge.net/p/hermesjms/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/HermesJMS/

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache Camel (http://camel.apache.org) to write a test harness. It has good support for testing & ActiveMQ.